# gradle java plugin "Jar" task from block API "from" section

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jar

I see following code is a valid syntax for a jar task configuration
My confusion is following that the Jar task gradle doc, specifies three "from" methods: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html But none of them match signature used in below code [image]
:

```
jar { // configure the jar archiving
  from {
    project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
      File file -> project.zipTree(file)
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to understand which `from` section is used according to the API, since signature does not match any method in API doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The from method takes `Object` as input argument, which can be everything.
The documentation of the method says that the values will be evaluated via `Project.files`

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:files(java.lang.Object[])

The documentation on that describes the different types it will accept, including Groovy Closures.

So the closure will be evaluated by `Project.files` and converted into an instance of `ConfigurableFileCollection`

Comment: This seems to commonplace in gradle land, where Object type is a very generic input for a bunch of functions and we can pass in closures as well.

Comment: Yeah, most Gradle APIs will accept Closures. Especially when tasks build on the results of each other it can be a very powerful tool to have Closure code lazily evaluated instead of at the build configuration stage. Often Closure is defined as separate method overloading, but I guess since file handling accepts more than a dozen differnt types they just opted for keeping it simple and declaring it as Object